# Forcing a dropdown list for an entity property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to keep track of employees in my database. I have two tables, Employees and Departments. The Employees table contains a foreign key relationship with Departments through a column named DepartmentID.

Here's my entity:

```
[Table(Name = "Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a first name")]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }        

    [Column]
    [DisplayName("Department")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a page that contains a form to add an employee. I'm passing the entity to my view page, and calling `<%: Html.EditorForModel() %>`

The problem is that the view creates a textbox for the DepartmentID.

How can I force the view to display a dropdown for DepartmentID that contains all the Departments in my database as the dropdown's list items? Is there a way to do this by just adding a metadata attribute to the property in my entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not going to be able to do it with just an attribute. You can use `Html.DropDownListFor`. You'll have to pass your view a list of all the departments as well.

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(  
    x => x.DepartmentID,  
    Model.Departments }  
) %>
```